# Missing IAP Apple Rejection

Tags: ios, flash, air, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

My app was rejected by apple with the following message:

> Missing IAPs
>
> We are unable to complete the review of your app since one or more of
>   your In App Purchases have not been submitted for review.
>
> Please be sure to take action and submit your In App Purchases AND
>   upload a new binary in iTunes Connect. Learn more about submitting In
>   App Purchases for review in the iTunes Connect Developer Guide.
>
> Once you've submitted your In App Purchases and uploaded a new binary,
>   we can proceed with your review.

I'm using Flash CS6 and I'm not using any IAP, anywhere in my app. I just use a network connection to save and load user data.
Is there anything wrong in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like whatever screening process the app store review team has in place mistakenly triggered that your app has IAP's enabled.

[Submit an appeal via this form](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/contact/appreviewboard/index.html) and see if they will reconsider.

Otherwise, you'll have to "dive deeper" into your code to see if there's anything you might have mistakenly enabled or embedded in your project that would have caused Apple to believe you were doing IAP's.  At the same time, I'm wondering if there's something in CS6 that might allow for IAP purchases which you and I both didn't know about?

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will try it.
And I am not using any external library or api, just pure flash. Also, I try to find in the cs6 configuration, and I think there is any configuration to activate the IAP